# Read Only asp drop down list

Tags: javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I'm working on an ASP.Net app

I have a drop down that, under some conditions, should be 'read only', that is, the user can't change it but, on a post back its selected value can be read.

Now I know that the readOnly attribute is not available for drop downs
so I'm trying to build a method that simulates this

so I wanted to make a javascript function that doesnt let the user 'open' the drop down to select an item. is this possible?

here's the example

```
function MakeDropDownReadOnly(dropDownId, makeReadOnly){

    var myDropDown = document.getElementById(dropDownId);

    if(makeReadOnly){
        //Block drop down

    }
     else{
          //Unblock drop down
     }
}
```

tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it disabled then in form submit (using JavaScript) enable it again so the value will be sent to the server.

Sample code to enable upon submitting:

```
document.getElementById("<%=DropDown1.ClientID%>").disabled = false;
```

Comment: tks, that does the trick without the need to post back just to enable/disable controls. I added on the form tag 'onsubmit' = "EnableControlsAgain();" and it's working fine

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use Enabled="false"?

Comment: I'm trying to enable/disable on client side and that way on server side its not possible to read the value

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried "Enabled" property of the DropDownList?

Answer (score 0):

`onfocus="this.blur()"` might work to prevent a user to interact with the select.